# How do I remove bytestrings left over from decompression from a string?

Tags: python, bz2

I have a bunch of strings which are sentences that look something like this:

`Having two illnesses at the same time is known as \xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d and it can make treating each disorder more difficult.`

I encoded the original string with `.encode()` then compressed with python's `bz2` library.

I then decompressed with `bz2.decompress()` and used `.decode()` to get it back.

Any ideas how I can conveniently remove these bytestrings from the text or avoid characters like quotes not getting decoded properly?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think these characters are not getting encoded properly?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't what I meant; I'll edit. They're not getting decoded.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I just tried encoding a string using `.encode()`, then compressing it using `bz2.compress()`, then proceeded to `bz2.decompress()` which already gave a good output. Even after `.decode()` the output was correct. Using Python 3.8.1

Comment: Hey guys, I got an answer. I did it correctly in most of my code by apparently in a couple of instances I accidentally just used str() on a bytestring. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you mistakenly assigned the above byte string “sentence” to an object of type `str`. Instead, it needs to be assigned to a *byte* string object and interpret it as a sequence of UTF-8 bytes. Compare:

```
b = b'... known as \xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d and ...'
s = b.decode('utf-8')
print(b)
# b'... known as \xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d and ...'
print(s)
# ... known as “comorbidity” and ...
```

Either way, the issue is unrelated to compression: a lossless compression (such as bzip2) roundtrip never changes the data:

```
print(bz2.decompress(bz2.compress(b)).decode('utf-8'))
# ... known as “comorbidity” and ...
```

Comment: Thanks! You were exactly right. I missed one line where I used str() on it without decoding. >.< Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you didn't actualy decode the data properly as interpreting `\xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d` as bytes and decoding yields a very sensible string:

```py
>>> b"\xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d"
b'\xe2\x80\x9ccomorbidity\xe2\x80\x9d'
>>> _.decode()
'“comorbidity”'
```

Either that or the original data was improperly generated / decoded in the first place (before it was encoded to UTF-8 and compressed) e.g. a UTF8 data source was read as ISO-8859-1 (which is essentially a passthrough).

So these are the bits I'd look at:

- do you actually properly decode after decompressing
- is the *original* data correct

Comment: Thanks! The other answer was first but this would have done it too.